# Accordion looping on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I have a menu that is hidden in an accordion when viewing on screens less than 600px.
On screens larger than 600px the menu is visible.

`jsfiddle`- http://jsfiddle.net/ashatron/zbzqoz2f/

it works ok, but when i resize the window to be greater than 600px, then go back to less than 600px then press view sitemap it **loops** the animation multiple times.

I think its running the function for every resize event, which is queing up the accordion and then looping it. But I'm not sure how best to order the syntax to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
footernavmenufn = function() {

var current_width = $(window).width();

if (current_width < 600) {
   $('.footer-accordion-head').show();
   $('.footer-accordion-body').hide();

   $('.footer-accordion-head').click(function () {
   $(".footer-accordion-body").slideToggle('400');
  // console.log('hmmm');
return false;
}).next().hide();
} else {
   $('.footer-accordion-head').hide();
   $('.footer-accordion-body').show();
}
};


$(document).ready(function () {
footernavmenufn();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
footernavmenufn();
//console.log('OMG-WHY-YOU-NO-WORK');
 });
```

Comment: Each call to `.click()` adds another binding. And, none of these are at any point being unbound. So, by continuing to resize the window while under under 600 pixels, you can end up with say 100 handlers, each prepped to queue up another `slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that everytime window is resized and the condition is met, you're binding a new click event handler, so after a while there'll be multiple event handlers causing chaos. Ideally your code should be something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.footer-accordion-head').click(function () {
    $(".footer-accordion-body").slideToggle('400');
    console.log('hmmm');
    return false;
  });
  $(window).resize(footernavmenufn);
  footernavmenufn(); // or $(window).trigger("resize");
});

footernavmenufn = function () {

  var current_width = $(window).width();

  if (current_width < 600) {
    $('.footer-accordion-head').show();
    $('.footer-accordion-body').hide();
  } else {
    $('.footer-accordion-head').hide();
    $('.footer-accordion-body').show();
  }
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/zbzqoz2f/2/)

Comment: brilliant! thats working a treat! thanks so much mate!
So what you have done is separated out the click slide toggle and width query.
So that the click slide toggle is only in the doc ready, but the width query is on the resize, so it doesnt run the slide toggle on every resize event... I think i get how it works, thanks dude! :D

is there a major difference between   $(window).resize(function(){

Comment: is there a major difference between
        $(window).resize(function(){
       footernavmenufn();
       });
and 
    $(window).resize(footernavmenufn);
    footernavmenufn();

not sure what the difference is :/

Comment: Well in the first case you're manually calling a function inside an anonymous function... in the second case the function you want to execute will be called directly, you can avoid an extra function call and code will be cleaner.. that's all .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this code? Crazy one. Remove it:

```
if (current_width < 600) {
   $('.footer-accordion-head').show();
   $('.footer-accordion-body').hide();

   $('.footer-accordion-head').click(function () {
   $(".footer-accordion-body").slideToggle('400');
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move the click declaration into the `$(document).ready` function.

at the moment everytime you resize the page that click function is being added again - so the repeat is once per page resize.
[forked jsfiddle with change](http://jsfiddle.net/zc9h5xzf/)